# Soundcards are not detected in Kubuntu only dummy output shows up in phonon

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, phonon

It seems that, in KDE, no sound cards will be recognized. The onboard card [does not work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1273508). But at least additional sound card ought to work: I've tried two different cards and they both are known to work, and do indeed work in a Live environment, but something has gone wrong with pulseaudio... In Phonon, there are no cards listed except for "Dummy Output", and there is no sound. Here are some outputs (after commenting out `; daemonize = no` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`):

#### `pulseaudio -vvvv`

```
richie@richie-desktop:~$ pulseaudio -vvvv
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 4.0
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option                                                                                                                                  
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014                                        
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 2 CPUs.                                                                                                                      
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes                                                                                                            
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no                                                                                                 
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no                                                                                                       
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no                                                                                                                  
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes                                                                                                               
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.                                                                                 
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is fb1f7a50fa35f51686a94d09522640ea.                                                                                    
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is c1.                                                                                                                  
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.                                                                                      
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/richie/.config/pulse.                                                                                  
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-4.0/modules.                                                                                
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no                                                                                                         
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.                                                                                                             
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.                                                                                                       
richie@richie-desktop:~$ amixer                                                                                                                            
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0                                                                                                                            
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined                                                                                                                     
  Playback channels: Mono                                                                                                                                  
  Mono: Playback [off]
```

#### `pacmd`

```
richie@richie-desktop:~$ pacmd list                                                                                                                        
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.                                                                                                   
>>> Memory blocks currently allocated: 1, size: 63.9 KiB.                                                                                                  
Memory blocks allocated during the whole lifetime: 1, size: 63.9 KiB.                                                                                      
Memory blocks imported from other processes: 0, size: 0 B.                                                                                                 
Memory blocks exported to other processes: 0, size: 0 B.
Total sample cache size: 0 B.
Default sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default channel map: front-left,front-right
Default sink name: auto_null
Default source name: auto_null.monitor
Memory blocks of type POOL: 1 allocated/1 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type POOL_EXTERNAL: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type APPENDED: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type USER: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type FIXED: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type IMPORTED: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
19 module(s) loaded.
    index: 0
        name: <module-device-restore>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 1
        name: <module-stream-restore>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 2
        name: <module-card-restore>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 3
        name: <module-augment-properties>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 4
        name: <module-switch-on-port-available>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: no
        properties:

    index: 5
        name: <module-bluetooth-policy>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau"
                module.description = "When a bluetooth sink or source is added, load module-loopback"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 6
        name: <module-bluetooth-discover>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Joao Paulo Rechi Vita"
                module.description = "Detect available bluetooth audio devices and load bluetooth audio drivers"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 7
        name: <module-native-protocol-unix>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: no
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 8
        name: <module-default-device-restore>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 9
        name: <module-rescue-streams>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "When a sink/source is removed, try to move their streams to the default sink/source"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 10
        name: <module-null-sink>
        argument: <sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'>
        used: 0
        load once: no
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Clocked NULL sink"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 11
        name: <module-always-sink>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
                module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 12
        name: <module-intended-roles>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based of intended roles of devices"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 13
        name: <module-suspend-on-idle>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 14
        name: <module-systemd-login>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 15
        name: <module-position-event-sounds>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 16
        name: <module-filter-heuristics>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
                module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 17
        name: <module-filter-apply>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: yes
        properties:
                module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
                module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"
                module.version = "4.0"
    index: 18
        name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
        argument: <>
        used: -1
        load once: no
        properties:
                module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
                module.description = "Command line interface protocol (UNIX sockets)"
                module.version = "4.0"
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <auto_null>
        driver: <module-null-sink.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE 
        priority: 1000
        volume: 0:   3% 1:   3%
                0: -87.39 dB 1: -87.39 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 100%
                     0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max request: 344 KiB
        max rewind: 344 KiB
        monitor source: 0
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
        module: 10
        properties:
                device.description = "Dummy Output"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <auto_null.monitor>
        driver: <module-null-sink.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE 
        priority: 1000
        volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 100%
                     0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0.00 ms
        max rewind: 344 KiB
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
        monitor_of: 0
        module: 10
        properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
                device.class = "monitor"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
4 client(s) logged in.
    index: 0
        driver: <module-systemd-login.c>
        owner module: 14
        properties:
                application.name = "Login Session c1"
                systemd-login.session = "c1"
    index: 1
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                application.name = "KMix"
                native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
                native-protocol.version = "28"
                application.process.id = "1876"
                application.process.user = "richie"
                application.process.host = "richie-desktop"
                application.process.binary = "kmix"
                application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
                window.x11.display = ":0"
                application.process.machine_id = "fb1f7a50fa35f51686a94d09522640ea"
                application.process.session_id = "c1"
                application.icon_name = "kmix"
    index: 2
        driver: <protocol-native.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                application.name = "KMix"
                native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
                native-protocol.version = "28"
                application.process.id = "1504"
                application.process.user = "richie"
                application.process.host = "richie-desktop"
                application.process.binary = "kdeinit4"
                application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
                window.x11.display = ":0"
                application.process.machine_id = "fb1f7a50fa35f51686a94d09522640ea"
                application.process.session_id = "c1"
    index: 3
        driver: <cli.c>
        owner module: 18
        properties:
                application.name = "UNIX socket client"
0 card(s) available.
0 sink input(s) available.
0 source outputs(s) available.
0 cache entrie(s) available.
```

#### `cat /etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
>>> richie@richie-desktop:~$ cat /etc/pulse/default.pa 
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
#
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
# Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA.

# This startup script is used only if PulseAudio is started per-user
# (i.e. not in system mode)

.nofail

### Load something into the sample cache
#load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/gtk-events/activate.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-hotplug /usr/share/sounds/startup3.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-coldplug /usr/share/sounds/startup3.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-access /usr/share/sounds/generic.wav

.fail

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

### Automatically augment property information from .desktop files
### stored in /usr/share/application
load-module module-augment-properties

### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
#load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif

.ifexists module-android-audio-hal.so
load-module module-android-audio-hal
.endif

### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix

### Network access (may be configured with paprefs, so leave this commented
### here if you plan to use paprefs)
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish

### Load the RTP receiver module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-rtp-recv

### Load the RTP sender module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor

### Load additional modules from GConf settings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
### Please keep in mind that the modules configured by paprefs might conflict with manually
### loaded modules.
.ifexists module-gconf.so
.nofail
load-module module-gconf
.fail
.endif

### Automatically restore the default sink/source when changed by the user
### during runtime
### NOTE: This should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
### that look up the default sink/source get the right value
load-module module-default-device-restore

### Automatically move streams to the default sink if the sink they are
### connected to dies, similar for sources
load-module module-rescue-streams

### Make sure we always have a sink around, even if it is a null sink.
load-module module-always-sink

### Honour intended role device property
load-module module-intended-roles

### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
load-module module-suspend-on-idle

### If autoexit on idle is enabled we want to make sure we only quit
### when no local session needs us anymore.
.ifexists module-console-kit.so
load-module module-console-kit
.endif
.ifexists module-systemd-login.so
load-module module-systemd-login
.endif

### Enable positioned event sounds
load-module module-position-event-sounds

### Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
#load-module module-role-cork

### Modules to allow autoloading of filters (such as echo cancellation)
### on demand. module-filter-heuristics tries to determine what filters
### make sense, and module-filter-apply does the heavy-lifting of
### loading modules and rerouting streams.
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply

# X11 modules should not be started from default.pa so that one daemon
# can be shared by multiple sessions.

### Load X11 bell module
#load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system

### Register ourselves in the X11 session manager
#load-module module-x11-xsmp

### Publish connection data in the X11 root window
#.ifexists module-x11-publish.so
#.nofail
#load-module module-x11-publish
#.fail
#.endif

### Make some devices default
#set-default-sink output
#set-default-source input
```

On the ALSA side of things, every sound card, including the onboard one, HDMI, and extra ones added in, works. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with pulseaudio?

Is there any way to get it to run properly and make sound work?

Comment: Pulseaudio gives you this message because it is already running in deamonized mode. To disable deamonized mode temporarily for troubleshooting you can enable `daemonize = no` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and run `pulseaudio -k`. What output are you getting then when running `pulseaudio -vvvv` again?

Comment: @LiveWireBT I get the same output after doing that.

Comment: @Braiam I have edited my question.

Comment: Uncomment `#load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` to `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` and restart the system.

Comment: @Braiam Well that got it detected. Sound is still just a continuous buzz, but it shows up in Phonon as it should...

Answer (score 0):

If you do `ps ax | grep pulse` you will notice pulseaudio already running:

```
➜  ~  ps ax | grep pulse
 3468 ?        S<l    0:55 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
➜  ~  pulseaudio -vvvv
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 4.0
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: i486-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 3.12-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.12.6-2 (2013-12-29)
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 1 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is bfcb4f8e26b936b5242f474c51c5e2a9.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 2.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/user/.pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-4.0/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

So the behaviour you are seeing is the desired by developers, if your sound doesn't work it would be for other motives

Comment: In other words pulseaudio runs daemonized by default and will start automatically after the user logs in or pulseaudio gets killed. The user thought the output was a symptom or a hint at the actual issue, but it isn't. Your answer does not answer the actual question and should be a comment instead.

Comment: @LiveWireBT "Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with pulseaudio?" aka, *Why the heck it says "E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running"*.

Comment: I see now that it was a potentially confusing question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into PulseAudio, check weather sound cards are up or not using `aplay -l`. If no sound card is found here then look into dmesg of the boot. See weather sound drivers are being loaded or not. You can also check by doing `lsmod | grep` snd. Pulseaudio is just an audio server. If the above things are up and running properly, PulseAudio should work.